# Getting website's time to set time range

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is there any way to get the current time of website in order to set range time for reaction?

e.g if current time of `website >= 14:00` && current time of `website < 15:00`

```
do reaction

else

another reaction
```

I want to do this checking type of fuction every 30' sec

EDITED

e.g If in my country the time is `14:00` and in another one is `19:00` I want to do the reaction to another country based in my country's time. Correct my if I do smthng wrong.

Comment: "current time of website" <-- what's this?

Comment: Server's time:
`<?php $b = time (); print date("H:i",$b) ; ?>`

Comment: I don't think you can get the current website time, because they haven't. A website current time is the current OS user time. So if I go through Stackoverflow.com in Paris, it is 11:39 (I actually come from Paris ^^). Else, if you go in Stackoverflow.com in another country you will have another time, but it is related to the USER current time, not website time (which doesn't exists).

Comment: @Gregory Ch: so, what prevents you from comparing `date("H:i",$b)`?

Comment: PhP Doesn't provides any Client data, because PhP is a server-side langage. You can access Client current time using Javascript.

Comment: @Zeratops soz I mean server's time.

Comment: Ok so in this scope you should search for accessing other server's information, which implies finding what is the server of a specific website.

Comment: @zerkms I tried comparing but the way that I did it was wrong. The webpage was looping and made a lot of time to respond.

Comment: @Gregory Ch: "I tried comparing but the way that I did it was wrong" --- we obviously cannot help you with code that you haven't provided.

Comment: @GregoryCh, tell me if I am wrong but obviously you want to compare **your** current time (so the Server-side current time) and the **user** one (which is the client-side time, and could be located to others country) ?

Comment: @Zeratops What I want is, to set a range time relating to my server-side's current time only. So, the results will be relating to my current time in every place of world. Even if someone has same time with me or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code for php file to fetch server time, name it t.php.

```
<?php
$b = time (); 
echo date("H",$b);
?>
```

and here is the code for other file on which you use ajax: Run this file using xamp/wamp.
Place both files in sane directory .

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "t.php",
        type: 'GET',        
        success: function(data){            
            if(data >= 9 && data < 10){ 
                alert('yes');
              // do something
            } else{ 
                alert('no');
                 // do something
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: It works like that. But after few minutes I got in console errors. If one condition is repeated (e.g data >= 9 && data < 10) for second time, how can we avoid of doing something? The only case that would display e.g alert yes would be if the previous functioned result was different from the current.

Comment: This is the error:
GET http://domain/time.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4send jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4m.extend.ajax jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4(anonymous function)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution:
you can find current time of website using javascript because it is a client side scripting language

In php I think there is no way to find client's time (not sure), That's why I am using jquery.
to use it in php file use ajax.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
function call_notification_count() {
        var todaydate = new Date(); // current time of browser. or you can say Time of client's location
        var month = todaydate.getMonth()+1+"";if(month.length==1)  month="0" +month;
        var date = todaydate.getDate()+"";if(date.length==1) date="0" +date;
        var year = todaydate.getFullYear();
        var hours = todaydate.getHours();
        var minutes = todaydate.getMinutes();
        var seconds = todaydate.getSeconds();
        var todaytime = hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
        var todaydateonly = year+"-"+month+"-"+date+" ";        
        alert(todaytime);
        if(hours >= 14){
                // do something
        }else{
                // do something
        }
    }
    setInterval(call_notification_count, 3000); // Set time intervel here like for every 30 sec.
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need jquery here?

Comment: The time here is relating to client's time. I made wrong previoysly. Instead of server's time I wrote client's time. So is there a way to do this regarding to server's time?

Comment: PhP Doesn't provides any Client data, because PhP is a server-side langage. You can access Client current time using Javascript

As mentioned by  "Zeratops"  above

Comment: @Ishan Demon I want server-side's time. I wrote it 3 times now.

Comment: Yes then you can do this by creating a php function and To run that function after every 30 sec. you have to use CRON

Comment: @IshanDemon Can you give an example?